# Is there an R command to show all functions defined in the environment?

Tags: r, function, environment

Is there an R command that shows all functions defined in the environment? 
For example, ls() shows all objects in the environment, but I need one that shows only the functions. I need to take all functions defined in the environment and since these are many, listing them is not suitable. Also because, every time I add a new function, I have to modify the list.

Comment: `as.character(lsf.str())`